# Upload to iTunes Connect Fails from Xcode 7 and Application Loader

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, application-loader

Application Loader says:

> Unable to upload your package.
>
> The `Info.plist` in the package must contain the `CFBundleVersion` key.
>   The `Info.plist` in the package must contain the `CFBundleShortVersionString` key.

And during the Archive upload `Xcode 7.3.1` says:

> "iTunes Store operation failed.
>
> No version found for 
>   `'adamId - platform' (1138008288-Mac OS X App)`. If this problem persists for more
>   than 24 hours, please contact your Apple representative."

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I got it to work but it wasn't using Application Loader with any particular version. I had to alter some attributes in the info.plist. Namely one of which was the minimum system version... this is used primarily for Mac Apps which mine is not. Also I had to change the Minimum OS Version for deployment to 9.0 instead of 8.0 and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you change your Application Loader Version.

Downloaded 3.0 as mentioned and it worked.

Comment: I got it to work but it wasn't using Application Loader with any particular version. I had to alter some attributes in the info.plist. Namely one of which was the minimum system version... this is used primarily for Mac Apps which mine is not. Also I had to change the Minimum OS Version for deployment to 9.0 instead of 8.0 and that fixed it.